# What is the life cycle of a framework or library?

Tags: reactjs, frameworks, application-lifecycle

What is the life cycle of a framework or library?**strong text**

Comment: You may find why should we use it and how here : 
https://medium.com/@krinasoni28/react-life-cycle-hooks-15d7c181d5b1

Answer (score 0):

Life cycle actually means events the library/framework fires whenever certain things happen so that if you want to do anything at that time, you can tap into that event.

For e.g - React has multiple life cycle events - componentWillMount, componentDidMount etc.
Before rendering the component, React fires **componentWillMount** and when it gets rendered, it fires **componentDidMount**. You can define these events in your component and do anything at those events.